# pandas how to convert a two-dimension dataframe to a one-dimension dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

suppose I have a dataframe with multi columns.

```
    a   b   c
1           
2           
3
```

How to convert it to a single columns dataframe

```
1   a
2   a
3   a
1   b
2   b
3   b
1   c
2   c
3   c
```

please note that the former is a Dataframe other than Panel

Comment: ignore the missing value, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().melt('index', var_name='col').set_index('index')[['col']]
print (df)
      col
index    
1       a
2       a
3       a
1       b
2       b
3       b
1       c
2       c
3       c
```

Or [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) with `DataFrame` constructor::

```
a = np.repeat(df.columns, len(df))
b = np.tile(df.index, len(df.columns))
df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=b, columns=['col'])
print (df)
  col
1   a
2   a
3   a
1   b
2   b
3   b
1   c
2   c
3   c
```

Comment: jez if I knew you are about to answer, I never would have dared :)

Comment: Nice answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

another way is,

```
pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df.index, df.columns.values))).set_index([0])
```

Output:

```
   1
0   
1  a
1  b
1  c
2  a
2  b
2  c
3  a
3  b
3  c
```

For exact output:

use `sort_values`

```
print pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df.index, df.columns.values))).set_index([0]).sort_values(by=[1])

   1
0   
1  a
2  a
3  a
1  b
2  b
3  b
1  c
2  c
3  c
```

Comment: I dont understand why you commnet nice answer :) +1

Comment: @jezrael - because, the way you have implemented through numpy impressed me :)